# Put form input fields with same class name into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some fields like this:

```
[1] [2] [3] with attributes: name=item1,item2,item3 and class = item
```

What I want to do is get all three fields into an array:

so:

```
array = [1,2,3];
```

Is there a way to do this using the unique class attribute: "item" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` method to return an array out of attribute:

```js
var items = $('.item').attr('name').split(','), // convert to array
  arr = [].map.call(items, function(value) { // use 
    return +value.match(/\d/)[0]; // return the number value from the array "items"
  });

$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p name='item1,item2,item3' class='item'>item</p>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the items and loop through them. Adding each one to your list.

```
var items = [];
$('.item').each(function(index, value){
  //where value is an input
  items.push(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `$(".items").toArray()` to get the same result, possibly one that works.